# tkinter geometry giving resize error even giving the right syntax

Tags: python, tkinter

when using tkinter geometry I get this error

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.geometry('500x 500')
window.title("hello")

window.mainloop()
```

even tho i use 'x' in lowercase no '*'

still m getting this error:

```
return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "500x 500"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentally put a space after the X.

Just remove the extra space everything should work as expected :)

```py
# Before
window.geometry('500x 500')

# After
window.geometry('500x500')
```

Final code should be:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.geometry('500x500')
window.title("hello")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have tried that too but still it give me the same here

Comment: @RaunakTamang Really? It works for me: https://imgur.com/a/MhdsV1X  Are you getting the same error as you stated in your question?

Comment: yes the sameerror :  return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "500x 500"

Comment: In the error you just provided, it still has the space after the X. Could you provide a screenshot of the code and the error?

Comment: Try the final code which I have provided in my answer above.

Comment: hey its working but  I don't why both codes are identical

Comment: I got it, the reason of the error is that I was putting '500x 500' instead of '500x500'

Comment: @cyberhoax If my answer solved your issue, please accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer